R Package with C++/Armadillo: not enough memory
I'm developing a Bayesian modeling package for R in which I'm using C++ with Armadillo for linear algebra operations. For applications involving a large matrix X (by large I mean 30+ millions lines with at least 10 columns), the R program crashes, simple as that.
Here are some important facts:

I know that the problem is related with how much RAM I have available at my PC;
The error occurs just by passing the matrix into C++, without doing any kind of multiplication;
X is known as design matrix and being so I need it completely for calculating things like (X'X)^{-1};
The X matrix may be sparse: being a design matrix, it can be used to represent categorical variables and be, for example, a matrix 30m x 10 in which each row have, at least, 8 zeros. In this specific case, 80% of the elements are zeros. But not necessarily: X can have dimensions such as 30m x 10 and be dense, with all the elements different from zero.

I have already tried using Eigen instead of Armadillo but found out that Armadillo seems to be somewhat faster than Eigen, and neither Eigen solved the problem. I'm looking for options to deal with this situation on big data applications (maybe changing the linear algebra library?) that can be available and used by people with minimal effort.
Edit: the C++ code is publicly available at GitHub, the function being the one used at line 458. The application in question would require to share the entire database (which I'm not allowed to do), so here goes a code that tries to reproduce the problem:
# Loading the package
library(lnmixsurv)

# Generating dataset
n <- 4e+07
set.seed(15)
data <- data.frame(cat = factor(sample(1:20, n, TRUE)),
                   time = rexp(n, 0.2),
                   status = rbinom(n, 1, 0.7))

# Fitting the model
model <- survival_ln_mixture(Surv(time, status) ~ cat,
                             data,
                             mixture_components = 4,
                             em_iter = 0,
                             show_progress = TRUE)

And yes, I was wrong, the problem was not related to the C stack usage limit, but with the amount of memory required to do the required operations. The R just crashes because the system doesn't have enough memory. So, I'm changing the title.

If you really need to use all the data (and can't just down-sample), the easiest solution is probably to buy or rent computing resources.
